# displaying results based on combobox selection

Tags: php

I have a dynamic combobox and I have my Fetch button. When a user selects a value from combobox and clicks fetch button, all the other related values are displayed in a textbox for the user to edit and update records. And that works fine.

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">   
  <select name="ID" id="select">
     <?php display_Id();?>
  </select> 
  <input type="submit" name="Fetch" id="Fetch" value="Fetch" />
</form>

function display_Id() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Flight";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Failed to fetch records");
    confirm_query($result);

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $flightNum = $rows['FlightNo'];
        echo "<option value=\"$flightNum\" ";
        echo " selected";
        echo "> $flightNum </option>";
    }       
}
```

The problem is in the Fetch button. When user clicks Fetch, other values are displaying but the selected value from combobox is refreshing. How to make the values remain selected even after pressing the Fetch button?

Comment: Please add your `display_Id()` code to question in order to get help.

Comment: You will need to mark the option as selected in your `display_Id()` method. You can get the selected option's value from `$_POST['ID']`

Comment: I have added display_Id();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is incomplete in the sense, that you don't have your  `dislay_Id()` code shown here.  However, Generally speaking, you should add  `selected` after `<option value="something"` programmatically,

Code should be something like this:

```
function displayId(){
  if($value[x]== $currentValue) {
    echo "<option value='$value[x]' selected>sth</option>";
  } 
  else
  {
    echo "<option value='$value[x]'>sth</option>";
  }
}
```

EDIT:: Your code adds a "selected" to each of the values, you must only add a "selected" to a current value.

So, your code must look like this:

```
echo "<option value=\"$flightNum\" ";

if($_POST['ID'] == $flightNum)
{        
  echo " selected";
}
echo "> $flightNum </option>";
```

Comment: I have added "selected" in <option>. The problem is that after clicking Fetch button, the value from combobox is not selecting.

Comment: Ok I did this and the Fetch button is not letting the value from combobox being selected

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you meant by `Fetch button is not letting the value from combobox being selected`

Comment: Ok I tried this code in another php file and it worked. It wasn't working before because function diplay_Id(); was in another file called functions.php and in my edit.php I had require("function.php"); Thanks. This code works and it is selecting :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $flightNum = $rows['FlightNo'];
    echo "<option value=\"$flightNum\" ";
    if($_POST['ID'] == $flightNum)
    {
        echo " selected";
    }
    echo "> $flightNum </option>";
}
```

Comment: great! could you change this to the accepted answer for future visitors? :)

Comment: you have not, and it was posted before the answer you did accept.